# Need help defining the type of a generic Class Mixin function

Tags: typescript

Give the following code:

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};

export const PositionedNodeMixin = <C extends Constructor>(superclass: C) => {
  return class NodePositionableAbilities extends superclass {
    pos: string = "";
  };
};

export const NodeChildrenMixin = <C extends Constructor>(superclass: C) => {
  const x = class NodeChildrenAbilities extends superclass {
    children: Record<string, boolean | undefined> = {};
  };
  return x;
};

class BaseNode {
  id: string;
  constructor() {
    this.id = Math.random().toString();
  }
}
```

That I can use like so:

```
const MixedClass = PositionedNodeMixin(NodeChildrenMixin(BaseNode));

const mixedClassInstance = new MixedClass();

console.log(mixedClassInstance.id);
console.log(mixedClassInstance.children);
console.log(mixedClassInstance.pos);
```

What would be the type that would allow us to write the code like so:

```
const MixedClass2 = mix(BaseNode, [PositionedNodeMixin, NodeChildrenMixin])
```

But will maintain the typesafety for the `pos` and `children` keys.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOxpRN) meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes it does! Thank you! Oh wow, this is exactly what I wanted. If you could kindly point me a resource that I can use to learn and be able to write such a thing I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's augment your `Constructor` definition so that it is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the instance type:

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

That will make it easier to write the types in what follows.

---

My inclination here would be to define `mix()`'s call signature like this:

```
declare function mix<S extends object, M extends any[]>(
    superclass: Constructor<S>,
    mixins: [...{ [I in keyof M]: (c: Constructor<S>) => Constructor<M[I]> }
    ]
): Constructor<S & IntersectTuple<M>>
```

Let's walk through that.  The function is generic in the type parameter `S` corresponding to the instance type of the `superclass` argument.  So if `superclass` is of type `Constructor<Super>`, then `S` is just `Super`.

It's also generic in the type parameter `M` corresponding to the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of instance types of the classes returned by the elements of the the `mixins` argument.  So if `mixins` is `[FooMixin, BarMixin, BazMixin]`, which return `Constructor<Foo>`, `Constructor<Bar>` and `Constructor<Baz>`, respectively, then `M` would be just `[Foo, Bar, Baz]`.

The type of `mixins` is a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) over the numberlike indices `I` of `M`, where the `I`th element of `mixins` is of type `(c: Constructor<S>) => Constructor<M[I]>`, as it accepts `superclass` as an input, and produce a constructor of the `I`th element of `M` (of [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `M[I]`).

By the way, that mapped type is wrapped in `[...`/`]` and is thus a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types).  That does very little to the type of `mixins`, but it gives the compiler a hint that we'd like it to infer a tuple type for `M` and not an unordered array type.  This is somewhat important given the return type of `mix()`.

That return type is `Constructor<S & IntersectTuple<M>>`, where `IntersectTuple<M>` is a utility type that evaluates to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of all the elements of `M`.  So if `S` is `Super` and `M` is `[Foo, Bar, Baz]`, then the return type will be `Constructor<Super & Foo & Bar & Baz>`.  That intersection means that the return type will construct instances of all those types at once.  So it will construct things that are `Super` *and* `Foo` *and* `Bar` *and* `Baz`.

We need to define `IntersectTuple`; here's one way to do it:

```
type IntersectTuple<T extends any[]> =
    { [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void }[number] extends
    (x: infer R) => void ? R : never;
```

It works via the rules for [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) which say that if multiple inference candidates appear in a *contravariant* position (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) ) then the resulting inferred type will be the intersection of all those candidates. (Also see [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218) for more about this general technique.)

---

Okay, let's test it!

```
const MixedClass2 = mix(BaseNode, [PositionedNodeMixin, NodeChildrenMixin]);
// const MixedClass2: Constructor<
//  BaseNode & 
//  PositionedNodeMixin<Constructor<{}>>.NodePositionableAbilities & 
//  NodeChildrenMixin<Constructor<{}>>.NodeChildrenAbilities
// >
const mixedClassInstance2 = new MixedClass2();
// const mixedClassInstance2: 
//   BaseNode & 
//   PositionedNodeMixin<Constructor<{}>>.NodePositionableAbilities & 
//   NodeChildrenMixin<Constructor<{}>>.NodeChildrenAbilities
mixedClassInstance2.id; // (property) BaseNode.id: string
mixedClassInstance2.children // (property) NodeChildrenAbilities.children: 
//   Record<string, boolean | undefined>
mixedClassInstance2.pos // (property) NodePositionableAbilities.pos: string
```

Looks good.  The type of `MixedClass2` is a constructor of the intersection of `BaseNode` and `NodePositionAbilities` and `NodeChildrenAbilities`, and so `mixedClassInstance2` has all the expected properties coming from the expected places.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqUAvFAN4C+AfCVAhAO5QAUAdOwIaoDmSAXFA4IQAbQC6AShI0CAbgCwAKCUQAHmFzAomRCigAFOEgCWwY4ggATAHJxLEALLHVxhLTwwoa4BASWksLpoWDioVMxI6JComAA2HEj8sFLENGRKUJlQqBDA6KhucQkBtvaGJmaIHABGsRAAgtXGsabGEAHevv5QkdFFieQZWcMaSSiorty0AETTCorDFPNLSirqmtpBUKUQMAAWzZY5CE4ubqQeXqo+fgHwyMHYuOG9EDHxiQIwKWlDmToPKCqWj9Ep2XYHWJHXyNZqtdpXG7dV7vYqDBbDLKYSHQhACABKEB0qEseHGkwANFBqnA4HUhFAAD5QdB+CAAM1cVhopEo80W-KyOTyBSBy3mSlBUAAQgkIDt0cNjJYBOSENxBf8ghgnqhmFJ0hjMVBgAckKxlbQHBxTaxUEJLHAALb61g4ADKaEm+s1UAoSn9yiDAL0pysMA+AVI5VaFhs4NOrmYO32h2OiYQzFlSHl4IkEglihDWidznDkYAkg8hJhoKR6Eww5YI8Ufasi7o6RBWLE4NxmKXVOXilWUDXu8qC5LO3Ue32B2Xm5Xqwha6xsWnfFOO8gu3P+4Ph4lR8Bx6xRtv2+3QJAoFWfKgc9gCFE6oREV0AkJRGIeX9yFAIgVlArhQAA1hAIBwOyUAEGIAjMKoAgEEBkjSFAABucCWhQIgIOgTrVG8Ygfrc-6IQIrjsm8UD4j8mHYZYUAAPy0VAAj0BhbyFko9hFDkUDsqy2DmG4g54O6pHdHA1QAFZEsAVIOFJX7COI4T-iioJfNqIS4BJVAUv+g6uEkIjsKwZCAcBoEQVBMEOPBLCYDpDw6qEBn0fc4x6fgDioTQgbDGISgSK5Pm6hJUAAGR3ggD5PsAL5gG+DhUFQ7bFlATYtokABMtCDlmco7FSIgxpU9DxvYGZUimOLps4riSPMAD0rWbICOWRnl4WPB5SjtZk2a5vYMVQINHUGEYsZVTsGYeLpkWUOlrA7BVok1HUsItGYCKxZNmT1ZuJxNQgi1ub5eArVQa3gqmULHDt8JIIdGU7noh5LiOK61gV9aMNli65UgeVtooQ1ZV9IMnuOvUTRDU0yiV4LjYdmQbXG81nRdEUeTdd1lDNlVbQ0TS7W0AQHYjWTHY9vgLd5-X6QTdO4s9e2vYo0PLmOq4QHlFqWLIUBDcwYCoHA0SgFII07ELqpeuqSg8z9fN-euDW+KLHXi5L0sgFIbNPeTL2aydBJErgpJqtwVI0l2DLMqy9iclV72q8ev0C+eRg6ywEtS28MvbOCmMIKTHOU77YxK9wQA)

Comment: This is an amazing answer and a lesson in TypeScript. Thank you kindly. I'll remember to check this answer and then visit your profile for more answers like this one. :)